# Understanding the following event.

Tags: probability-theory, elementary-set-theory

Given a sequence of measurable sets $\{A_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$, consider 
the following set

$$A= \bigcup_{\ell=1}^\infty \left(A_\ell \cap \bigcup_{n=\ell+1}^\infty \left(A_n \cap \bigcup_{m=n+1}^\infty 
        \left(A_m \cap \bigcup_{k=m+1}^\infty A_k\cap  \cdots \right) \right)  \right).$$
What is this set? Does it means that "infinitely many of the $A_n$'s occur"? And if so, is there an easier way to write down the set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following statements are equivalent:

1. $\omega \in A$.
2. There exists $\ell \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\omega \in A_\ell$ and 
   $$
   \omega \in \bigcup_{n=\ell+1}^\infty \left(A_n \cap \bigcup_{m=n+1}^\infty 
           \left(A_m \cap \bigcup_{k=m+1}^\infty A_k\cap  \cdots \right) \right)  .
   $$
3. There is an infinite subset $N \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ such that $\omega \in A_n$ for each $n \in N$.
4. $\omega \in \{\text{$A_n$ i.o.}\}$, that is:
   $$
   \omega \in \bigcap_{n = 1}^{\infty} \bigcup_{m = n}^{\infty} A_m.
   $$